# i3 with ArchLinux not showing Umlaut also no ß (scharfes S) and no ´

Tags: fonts, arch-linux

I can't write german "umlaut" letters neither can I write the "ß" letter also one of the parentheses "´" won't get displayed. Every time I see the weird box with a ? in it.

I have installed i3gaps

this is my font in .config/i3/config

```
font pagno:DejaVu Sans Mono 8
```

as a terminal I am using st but this is not an st problem only because this problem also appears with the build in i3-sensible-terminal (this one won't even show the question mark box)

All letters are shown properly when not in i3, it only seems to appear in the window manager.

[EDIT]

My locale.gen (the one in /etc) has a lot of commented out locales in it except of this one

```
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

My locale.conf only says

```
LANG=de-DE.UTF-8
```

When running `localectl`this is the feedback

```
System Locale: LANG=de-DE.UTF-8
VC Keymap: de-latin1
X11 Layout: n/a
```

Comment: Is your system configured to use UTF-8 encoding? Fonts probably aren't the issue here.

Comment: Yes UTF-8 is what I have chosen in the installation and everywhere else

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your `locale`s and output of `localectl`?

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if it helps, but can you please change the VC Keymap to de-utf8 or something similar with utf8? Then reboot and try again.

Comment: I have changed it to de-utf8 unfortunately this does not have any effect, I have also changed the X11 Layout to "de" this doesn't help either